# Detecting long clicks on a custom view?

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that extends `FrameLayout` and implements `ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener`. This View, as the class name suggests, is zoomable + pannable. Heres the custom views class: https://gist.github.com/Orbyt/23c82ce9002df6c318d4

I've been trying to find a way to detect long clicks on this View. I know that, usually, I could do something like this in the Activity:

```
GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);

mZoomableLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});

mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
      // do tasks here
    }
});
```

Using this, the View is no longer zoomable, presumably because its intercepting all the onTouch events instead of the implementation inside the Views class.

So my question is, what is the cleanest way to detect long clicks on this view?

Comment: `view#setOnLongClickListener` ?

Comment: @pskink How would you get the position of the event?

Comment: by overriding `onTouchEvent`

Comment: @pskink Do you have an example?

Comment: no, i have no example

Comment: @pskink Where are you suggesting I override onTouchEvent?

Comment: in a class where you want to detect long clicks

Comment: @pskink Not sure what your suggesting. Overriding onTouchEvent in the view does nothing, and im not sure how to implement it in the activity. Regardless, using `setOnClickListener()` makes the View no longer zoomable or pannable, which is what im avoiding. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: so how did you call `GestureDetector` when you didn't override that method?

Comment: @pskink What? That question doesnt make sense.

Comment: how did you call `GestureDetector` when you were not overriding `onTouchEvent`?

Comment: @pskink You just asked the same question, and again, it doesnt make sense. Also, im using `ScaleGestureDetector` in the View, no where in the code I posted am I using `GestureDetector`.

Comment: @Orbit did you figure out how to create a zoomable and pannable view supporting also long click?

Answer (score 3):

I had a pinch zoom circle on which I detected the normal click and long click.Code snippet is given below. In this I have detected long click and normal click by the time interval between MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.

May this help you.

```
     private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
     private float mScaleFactor = 1.0000000f;
     private long mStartClickTime;


     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     float x = event.getX();
     float y = event.getY();
     boolean right = x > (screenWidthPX / 2 + ((mLayoutHeight / 4) + 20) * mScaleFactor);
     boolean left = x < (screenWidthPX / 2 - ((mLayoutHeight / 4) + 20) * mScaleFactor);
     boolean top = y > (mLayoutHeight / 2 + ((mLayoutHeight / 4) + 20) * mScaleFactor);
     boolean bottom = y < (mLayoutHeight / 2 - ((mLayoutHeight / 4) + 20) * mScaleFactor);


     if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        if (left || right || top || bottom) {
            //  You may not need this condtion, I needed this because I had custom view of pinch zoom circle and, this condition detects the touch at outer area of circle.             
        } else {
            mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
     } else {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                mStartClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - mStartClickTime;

                if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                    if (left || right || top || bottom) {

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Normal CLick Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Long CLick Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you'll need to use touch slop to differentiate between actual movement and unintentional user finger movement (see ACTION_MOVE). Second if you're extending `FrameLayout` it's cleaner to override `onTouchEvent` instead of `this.setOnTouchListener` in `init()`.

Add variables to your custom View:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private int mTouchSlop;
private Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Long press!");
        //Do your long press stuff here.
    }
};
```

Inside `init()`:

```
mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();
```

In switch statement:

```
switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //Whatever you were doing previously here
        mHandler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
            dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
            dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;
            if(Math.abs(dx) > mTouchSlop || Math.abs(dy) > mTouchSlop) {
                //Actual movement
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
            } else {
                //Below touch slop, not a movement
                dx = 0;
                dy = 0;
            }
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
        //Whatever you were doing previously here
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
        //Whatever you were doing previously here
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
        //Whatever you were doing previously here
        break;
}
//Whatever you were doing previously here
```

Now all three functionalities are working.

If point of long click is needed make an abstract class that implements `Runnable` with floats x and y and fill them in `ACTION_DOWN`, then use coordinates in `run()`

Comment: So this is the implementation I had also found (though I didnt know about touchslop, thanks). On long press, Im opening a dialog, so I would want to notify the Activity about the long press event (as well as the x/y coordinates). What would be the best way to notify the Activity in the Runnables `run()` method in this case?

Comment: Make your activity implement `OnLongClickListener` and pass `this` to your custom view via overridden `setOnLongClickListener` for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry I didn't understand your problem at all.
Now in your MainActivity:

```
public yourMainConstructor()
{
  [...]

  GestureDetector sgd;
  sgd = new GestureDetector(context,new ScaleListener());

  [...]
}

class ScaleListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

        super.onLongPress(e);
    }
}
```

then override in your main class onTouchEvent()

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    sgd.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction()) 
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: This prevents the View from being zoomable or pannable.

Comment: Could you explain your example a bit? If you were referring to that code going into the Activity, it wouldnt know what View to listen on. If you were referring to that code going in the View, and the onTouchEvent() into the activity, then it wouldnt have a reference to the GestureDetector.